# Transfer Dependency Property value of a UserControl to a Control inside it

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a UserControl (Composite control) that can be shown as the following pseudo XAML code:

```
<UserControl>
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <Button />
  </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I use this custom control in a bunch of places and style some of them with a WPF Style. This style sets the Background property of the UserControl to a color. But this background color is drawn on UserControl's background surface, but I want it to be drawn only on TextBox control's background. This is what I get (Color=Red):

[alt text http://img261.imageshack.us/img261/8600/62858047wi3.png](http://img261.imageshack.us/img261/8600/62858047wi3.png)

If I bind the Background property of the UserControl to my TextBox control's background property, I get the following one:

[alt text http://img111.imageshack.us/img111/1637/30765795kw5.png](http://img111.imageshack.us/img111/1637/30765795kw5.png)

Now it also paints the background of the inner TextBox control but the Background color of the UserControl still exists. Are there any ways to remove that painting of UserControl's background?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I would suggest exposing your own property on your user control and binding to that inside your user control. For example:

```
<UserControl x:Name="_root" ...>
    ...
    <Button Background="{Binding ButtonBackground, ElementName=_root}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Another way would just be to explicitly set the background color of the `TextBox` to something.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kent. There are a number of ways that you can solve this problem.

But what about just using a Style in the UserControl to set the Background of the TextBox? Is there any special reason that the following wouldn't work for you?

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="StackOverflowQuestion.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="textBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Test" Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle}"/>
        <Button/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

If you truly want to utilize a property set on the user control and have it affect the internals of the user control, I would follow Kent's suggestion with one modification. I would Bind the Background of the TextBox instead so that whatever Background Brush the user set on the user control would flow (property value inheritance) to the Button. Or, in other words, the Background of the TextBox is really what you are trying to make different.

```
<UserControl x:Name="_root" ...>
    <TextBox Background="{Binding TextBoxBackground, ElementName=_root}"/>
    <Button/>
</UserControl>
```